# Xperia X10 SDK addon for android 2.3.3

Tags: java, android

i need Xperia X10 for android 2.3.3 android SDK addon but i cant find anywhere. i need it to test an app. where i can find it? in sony website there is only 1.6 version

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Android SDK` is completely backward compatible. So it should work fine on `Android 2.3.3`.

Here's the download link:
http://developer.sonymobile.com/downloads/tool/sony-ericsson-xperia-x10-add-on-for-the-android-sdk/

It doesn't mention the Android version but it was created on `December 8, 2011`. Perhaps it's what you're looking for.

Source: http://developer.sonymobile.com/downloads/tool/ (list of downloads from Sony)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Sonymobile developer world:
http://developer.sonymobile.com/downloads/tool/sony-ericsson-xperia-x10-add-on-for-the-android-sdk/